# PHP/Kohana Accessing variable defined in base controller in a view

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I have a variable defined in the class

> Controller_Application extends Controller_Template

I have defined a variable $Form_Errors inside the Controller_Application class as below

> public $Form_Errors = array();
>
> ```
> public function before() {
>     parent::before();
>     View::set_global('site_name', 'SiteName');
>     View::bind_global('Form_Errors', $Form_Errors); }
> ```

$Form_Errors is set by a method called `ManageErrors`, which is also defined inside `Controller_Application`. ManageErrors is called every time from  all other controllers when an exception or some errors occurs.

```
    public function ManageError($ErrorCode, $extraerrors=null) {
 if ($ErrorCode == Controller_Application::MsgEmailExists)
            array_push($this->Form_Errors, "Email provided is already in use.");


}
```

I am trying to access this $Form_Errors in the view, to display the errors message it holds. However, when i am trying to print it values, it always prints as NULL.

ManageError is accessed as below

```
public function action_index() {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('vsignin')->render();
        $this->ManageError(Controller_Application::MsgEmailExists);
}
```

in the vsignin.php

```
<?php if ($Form_Errors): ?>
<p class="message">Some errors were encountered, please check the details you entered.</p>
<ul class="errors">
<?php foreach ($Form_Errors as $message): ?>
    <li><?php echo $message ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Can someone help me to figure out why is th $Form_Errors is always printing NULL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to give $this->Form_Errors inside bind_global(), and that did the trick.